# Akka get response as ComletedStage from actor

Tags: akka

I am referring to api

`Patters.ask(actor, msg, duration);`
here is sample

```
class MyActor extends AbstractBehavior{
    interface Command{}
    interface SomeMessage implements Command{ INSTANCE}
    public Reveive<Comamnd> receive(){
       return newReceiveBuilder().onMessage(SomeMessage.class, this::someMessage).build();
    }
    private Behavior<Command> someMessage(SomeMessage ref){
       System.out.println("Dru lalal");
    }
}


 ActorRef<MyActor.Command> myActor = ...;
 Future<Object> future = Patterns.ask(myActor, SomeMessage.INSTANCE, Duration.ofMillis(10000));
```

What is gone be object ?

Obviously this won't compile. Some part of picture is missing, but javadoc doesn't state what.
Call "Patterns.ask" suppose to return future with object, those value is provided by actor as business logic. But there is not business logic in actor. I assume there is suppose to be some kind of convention or mapping for method that returns value with what "Patters.ask" triggers.

Same is true about back logic. I will not able to define receiver since it expect to return Receiver not SomeObject and thus, api want't let me bind result to some message. Only thing I can do is manually pass ComputableFuture

```
ComputableFuture<MyOBject>  future = new ComputableFuture<>();
myActor.tell(new Message(future));

    private Behavior<Command> someMessage(Message message){
         var result = compute();
         message.future.comlete(result);
    }
```

And here we go, I have manually manage everything, also issues with passing non serializable message, lifecycle of objects and so on.

Comment: Closed. Wrong objects is used. Instead of AskPattern.ask for new java typed dsl, I used classic Patterns.ask. Most of times new api objects has same object name but in different package and i got used to just to check package name and skip object name when playing with api. And here object name is different.

Comment: You can answer yourself and mark it as correct, thus helping people who might have similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong objects is used. Instead of "AskPattern.ask" for new java typed dsl, I used classic "Patterns.ask".

Most of times new api objects has same object name but located in different package. I  used to check only package name becouse while playing with in IDE they always next to each other since name is the same. I got used to ignore the classic "com.akka" objects while playing with api.

And here I got into trap, object name is different and not placed in IDE next to "classic" package object.